# Compile errror for compiling google play services

Tags: android

This is my app gradles file, I'm having trouble trying to build my apk since adding Google maps services. The error is specfically for compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0', in which it states that mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes.

```
app gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lunaemilia.fortius2"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'
    **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'**
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and the error I got for building the apk is:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: I seem to be able to build the app if I run the emulator and build the app at the same time but does anyone know how to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please put the following line into your android defaultConfig of your gradle build

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

You need to enable Multidex

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I did just that and nothing changed. I don't think that is the cause of the error.